# How to cumsum rows since a condition was last met in R

Tags: conditional-statements, cumsum

I would like to find the cumulative sum between two rows with different conditions.

My data looks like this:

```
row   diff   state
1     30     3
2     30     2
3     30     2
4     30     1
5     30     1
6     30     1
7     30     2
8     30     2
9     30     3
10    30     1
```

And for every row where state == 1, I want to know the cumulative diff between that row and the previous row where state == 3.

This is the end goal:

```
row   diff   state   lag  
1     30     3       NA
2     30     2       NA
3     30     2       NA
4     30     1       90
5     30     1       120
6     30     1       150
7     30     2       NA
8     30     2       NA
9     30     3       NA
10    30     1       30
```

I have tried:

```
df$lag[df$state == 1] <- cumsum(df$diff[df$state == 3])
```

But this just gave me the cumsum since the start of state == 1:

```
row   diff   state   lag  
1     30     3       NA
2     30     2       NA
3     30     2       NA
4     30     1       30
5     30     1       60
6     30     1       90
7     30     2       NA
8     30     2       NA
9     30     3       NA
10    30     1       30
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried adding the new column and cumulative sum of diff (df$lag[df$state == 1] <- cumsum(df$diff[df$state == 3])) but this just gives me the cumulative difference since the start of state == 1, not since state == 3.